# How to hyphenate a whole number and fraction as an adjectival modifier

Tags: hyphenation, compound-adjectives

When a fraction is used as part of a compound adjective it is conventionally hyphenated: e.g. *a quarter-million pounds*.

And when a whole number and a fraction are used together, it is conventional to not include a hyphen between the whole number and fraction: *one and seven-eights* rather than *one-and-seven-eighths*

But my question is what is conventional for hyphenating whole numbers and fractions when they form a compound adjective and precede a noun? Is it, if you will forgive the absurdity of the example, *a sixteen and one-quarter centimetre cake*, *a sixteen-and-one-quarter centimetre cake*, or *a sixteen-and-one-quarter-centimetre cake*?

Comment: *My* question is why wouldn't the nearest centimetre be accurate enough when measuring a cake? But anyway, I would hyphenate it as *a sixteen-and-one-quarter-centimetre cake*.